# Change the logo on chat.stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, chat

The site name was (finally) changed from "Travel Asnwers" to "Travel". However the old logo is still used on http://chat.stackexchange.com/

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just the old image being cached. I've forced a refresh.